# Returning to activity - blank white screen

Tags: android

I’m working on  an app that uses a webview on the main activity.  My question is: - when I return to the main activity from – settings for example – I just get a blank white screen. If I then press the back button the main activity is visible again.  Does anyone know what is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to provide some code.how do you launch and close the activities?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with code this will become more interesting, but a simple guess would be that you have to reload the web page during onResume on your main activity.